# Android : Stop Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am working on Android Application which have service class. I service class, I have to start a thread. It is working fine. But I need to stop the thread. I have used with

```
mThread.destroy();
mThread.stop();
```

but both are deprecated and i have used

```
mThread.interrupt();
```

but it still does not work.

code

```
public void Receivepatientattributes(byte[] readBuf, int len) {

    if (readBuf[8] == 6){

                pktcount++;

                byte pkmsb = readBuf[11];
                byte pklsb = readBuf[10];
                int pkresult = (pkmsb << 8) | ((int)pklsb & (0x00FF));

                System.out.println("Packet : "+pktcount+"   :   "+pkresult);
                if(pkresult == pktcount){                    

                    for(int i = 0, j = 14; i < len ; i++, j++) {
                        queue.add(readBuf[j]);
                    }
                    if(mThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW) {
                        mThread.start();
                        System.out.println("Start Thread ");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No Thread Found");
                    }

                } else {
                    displayToast("Packet Count Error");
                }
        }
    }
}
class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        do{
            if(queue.getFirst() == (byte)0x80) {
                System.out.println("absolu1 " + queue.getFirst());
                getabs_data();

            } 
        } while (queue.size() > 132);

        if(mThread.getState() == Thread.State.RUNNABLE) {
            mThread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/ is a nice article wrt interrupting threads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if(mThread.isInterrupted()){
    break;
}
```

inside your loop.

Comment: "Try this" isn't very helpful because it doesn't explain what was wrong or how to fix it in another case.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not provide any ways to stop a thread safely, it only provides **interruption**

You can **send interceptions to a thread**, **but this does not mean to kill a thread** . **Only if the target thread have the ability to respond to this interception, it can stop itself.**

For example, the target have a loop to check whether or no it is interrupted. Or if the target thread call some interrupt-able blocking functions, you can check the interruption in your catch block and stop this thread.

**For more information about java concurrency,  read the book `《Java Concurrency in Practice》`**

Answer (score 0):

Thread objects are controlled by the system, which can modify them outside of your app's process. For this reason, you need to lock access on a thread before you interrupt it, by placing the access in a synchronized block.

```
ublic class PhotoManager {
public static void cancelAll() {
    /*
     * Creates an array of Runnables that's the same size as the
     * thread pool work queue
     */
    Runnable[] runnableArray = new Runnable[mDecodeWorkQueue.size()];
    // Populates the array with the Runnables in the queue
    mDecodeWorkQueue.toArray(runnableArray);
    // Stores the array length in order to iterate over the array
    int len = runnableArray.length;
    /*
     * Iterates over the array of Runnables and interrupts each one's Thread.
     */
    synchronized (sInstance) {
        // Iterates over the array of tasks
        for (int runnableIndex = 0; runnableIndex < len; runnableIndex++) {
            // Gets the current thread
            Thread thread = runnableArray[taskArrayIndex].mThread;
            // if the Thread exists, post an interrupt to it
            if (null != thread) {
                thread.interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

}

For Further reference use this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html).

Answer (score 0):

In `CommunicationThread`, there's a do... while loop. Edit this loop slightly by adding `isInterrupted()` to the loop's condition:

```
    do{
        if(queue.getFirst() == (byte)0x80) {
            System.out.println("absolu1 " + queue.getFirst());
            getabs_data();

        } 
    } while (mThread.isInterrupted() && queue.size() > 132);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use Threads in android. Because it's not Thread-safe. Instead, use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which android sdk provided for this purpose.
FYI, for cancelling an AsyncTask you should call:

```
myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
```

Comment: Not true / oversimplified. `AsyncTask` itself is nothing more than a nicer way to use plain old `Thread`s. They are preferred when you implement the pattern they were meant for: tasks forked off from the main thread that need to report back to the main thread. `AsyncTask` provides a nice abstraction for the back and forth between main and background threads. They don't add any magic thread safety.